# Count(*) and Count(field_name) return difference output in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

There are two simple queries (because they are so simple, I am confused):

The first one:

```
select count(*) 
  from (select e.id as employee_id 
          from offic o
          left join employee e
            on o.employee_id = e.id)
 where employee_id is null
```

The second one:

```
select count(employee_id) 
  from (select e.id as employee_id 
          from offic o
          left join employee e
            on o.employee_id = e.id)
 where employee_id is null
```

The only difference between these two query is `count(employee_id)` and `count(*)`, the rest of them exactly are same but the result of them are difference.

The second query return zero while there are some null value.
What is wrong or some thing else that I do not know?

Comment: `count(employee_id)` doesn't Count rows with null `employee_id`. https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions032.htm#i82697

Comment: Check your `on e.employee_id = e.id` line of code. You are not joining to your `offic` table.

Comment: @Goran I have edited

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The second query counts rows that have a non-empty (`NOT NULL`) `EMPLOYEE_ID` column value. The first one counts *all* rows, regardless what's in `EMPLOYEE_ID`.

**[EDIT: a simple example which shows what's being counted]**

Reading comments below, well, some of them seem to be *wrong* (or I misunderstood  the author's intent) so - here you go (based on 11.2.0.4.0).

```
SQL> select * From a1_test;

      COL1       COL2       COL3
---------- ---------- ----------
         1                     3
         1          2
         1          2          3
                    2          3
                               3

SQL>
SQL> select
  2    count(*) cnt,
  3    count(1) cnt_1,
  4    count(2) cnt_2,
  5    count(3) cnt_3,
  6    --
  7    count(col1) cnt_c1,
  8    count(col2) cnt_c2,
  9    count(col3) cnt_c3
 10  from a1_test;

       CNT      CNT_1      CNT_2      CNT_3     CNT_C1     CNT_C2     CNT_C3
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         5          5          5          5          3          3          4
```

Comment: According to this so any time i want to get null value, i have to use count(*) instead of count(filed). is it?

Comment: @rezaramezanimatin you can use also columns that a not nullable or `*` or you can use  e.g. `Count(1)`

Comment: What is difference between count(*) and count(1)?

Comment: count(*) and count(1) are the same.  Also the same, count(2), count('wibble'), etc.

Comment: @rezaramezanimatin - *decades* ago, some optimizers were not well developed and could end up performing data retrieval when asked to perform `COUNT(*)` or `EXISTS (SELECT * ...` queries. Thus was born, at the time, advice to use `1` (or some other constant) instead. Unhelpfully, despite the fact that all mainstream optimizers know not to do data retrieval in these cases, some people will still offer this advice. (Not saying it's specifically why commenters here are saying it, just why you might encounter it, especially with old code/developers)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Thanks a lot

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever And further to that, the rationale I've heard for using `count(1)` instead of `count(*)` is that "count(*) has to read the whole row", perhaps based on incorrectly conflating this with the use of the asterisk in `select *`.

Comment: @DavidAldridge-  yes, that's precisely the "data retrieval" I was referring to. It was reasonable advice back at ~the turn of the century, but all of the mainstream optimizers caught onto this long ago.

Comment: In my opinion (unless I misunderstood what you're trying to say), @Ashokan, that's wrong interpretation. I edited my answer by providing an example which shows that - what you are saying - isn't right.

Comment: @AshokanSivapragasam - no, `COUNT(*)` **isn't** costly. You're parroting advice that is *decades* out of date, which is precisely what my previous comments are talking about.

Comment: @AshokanSivapragasam - and `count(1)` doesn't imply it only look at the first column. Numeric column (expression) positions are only ever relevant in an `order by`. Inside the count is just a constant number, as said earlier, and you can use a number higher than the number of items in the select list, or a string, or any other constant value. Except you don't have to, and it's better/clearer to use `count(*)`.

Comment: @AshokanSivapragasam: you are wrong. `count(1)` is essentially the same as `count(-42)` or `count('foobar')` - it simply supplies a non-null value. The parameter to the `count` function has nothing to do with column positions.

Comment: I removed my post with wrong assumptions to avoid any more confusions. I learnt it today. Sometimes mind starts to cook something if it is convinced with the theory. COUNT(constant) supplies non-null value.